# How to use label text as To address in System.Net.Mail

Tags: xml, vb.net

I have a VB.net program that is using System.Net.Mail to send an email.  I would like to send the an email to the text displayed in "Label1"  I'm pulling the email and assigning it to the label...   I have:

```
mail.To.Add(Me.Label1.Text) 'Sets the "To" address
```

However, this does not work.  How do I assign label1.text to  mail.To.Add?  It looks like it's not being assigned before the email message is being sent.  Perhaps I need to pull from the xml file differently?

```
Dim document As XmlReader = New XmlTextReader("C:\xml.xml")

            'loop through the xml file
            While (document.Read())

                Dim type = document.NodeType

                'if node type was element
                If (type = XmlNodeType.Element) Then

                    'if the loop found a <Site> tag
                    If (document.Name = "Site") Then

                        Me.Text = document.ReadInnerXml.ToString()

                    End If
                    'if the loop found a <Path> tag
                    If (document.Name = "Email") Then

                        Me.Label1.Text = document.ReadInnerXml.ToString()
                        Email = Me.Label1.Text
                        MsgBox("this is done")
                    End If


                End If

            End While

        Else

            MessageBox.Show("The filename you selected was not found.  ")
            Me.Close()
        End If

Try

            'Lets Send the Mail
            SmtpServer.Credentials = New  _
            Net.NetworkCredential("""") 'Assign the network credentials
            SmtpServer.Port = 25 'Assign the SMTP Port
            SmtpServer.Host = "10.0.0.0." 'Assign the Server IP
            mail = New MailMessage() 'Starts a mail message
            mail.From = New MailAddress("email") 'Sets the "FROM" address
            mail.To.Add(Me.Label1.Text) 'Sets the "To" address
            mail.CC.Add("") 'Sets the "CC" address
            mail.Subject = "Break Exception Report " & TodayDt & " - " & TodayEnd
            mail.IsBodyHtml = True
            mail.Body = time.ToString() 'this is to add another chart  You would use a seperate dataset obviously
            SmtpServer.Send(mail)
            MsgBox("mail send1")

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("error")
        End Try
```

Comment: What do you mean by "this does not work"? Any error messages? Did you debug the code and look at the value of Me.Label1.Text? Can you post more of your code?

Comment: What does not work exactly?  Are you getting compile errors?

Comment: It goes into the "Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("error")
        End Try"

I'll post more of the code

Comment: @Shmewnix, and what exactly is that error?

Comment: Please post the value of ex.ToString then

Comment: When coding a Catch for an exception it is useless to add a generic error message.  Show the exact error message, at least `ex.Message`

Comment: The parameter "Address" cannot be an empty string.

Comment: @Shmewnix, I really hate to ask this question--but what's the value of the `Text` on the `Label`?

Comment: Well, it is clear now. What is the Text property of your label?

Comment: For sending mail, use the SmtpClient, not the server

Comment: The label displays the correct email address.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud It displays the correct email in the label

Comment: Is this threaded code? I mean do you run the sending of the email in another thread? If so you can not read the label's contents directly, you would need to use `CStr(Me.Invoke(Function() Label1.Text))` instead. YOu can check this by using Label1.InvokeRequired.

Comment: It's all in "Form load"

Comment: That can also be a problem is the label is not fully initialized yet. Move it to Form.Shown

Comment: Same issue.  Parameter cannot be an empty string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with the Label1.Text as i found out. The error is this line:

```
mail.CC.Add("") 'Sets the "CC" address
```

You can't add an empty address to the CC collection. So remove it.

Comment: ARG!!!  I just found this and came back to type the comment.  Nice catch!  thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(Me.Label1.Text))
```

Comment: There is no `;` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
MailAddress to = new MailAddress(this.Label1.Text);
message.To.Add(to);
```

Comment: The MailAddressCollection has an overload of the Add method that takes a string.

Comment: There is no ; at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the SmtpClient class. Try it like that:

```
Dim sm As New SmtpClient(host, port) 'Host e.g. smtp.gmail.com, port usually 25 (non-SSL) or 587 (SSL)

Dim maFrom As MailAddress = New MailAddress(LogInEmail)
Dim maTo As MailAddress = New MailAddress(Label1.Text)
Dim mMsg As New MailMessage(maFrom, maTo)
mMsg.Subject = Topic
mMsg.Body = Message
sm.Send(mMsg)
```

You may have to enable SSL for the SMTP-Client, depending on your email-providers settings.

Comment: if I do mail.to.add ("email@email.com") it works...  it only has an issue when I try to use the email that is the label text.